# Search 2nd line of files and print filenames to stdout

Tags: sed, awk, grep, find

I have a few directories of ~10,000 files.  What's the quickest way to search each file and return the filename if the second line contains a specific string?

**Edited for clarity**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==2 {if (/some string/) print FILENAME; nextfile}' ./*
```

Some awks don't have "nextfile".

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear.  How do I search the second line for a specific string and then return the filename?

Comment: @chishaku Glenn's answer will print the second line of each file, you can then use `grep` normally to find the matches.

Comment: @chishaku Just use `if ($0 ~ /search string/) print FILENAME;` instead of `print FILENAME ...;`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure in high speed but should work too

```
for i in *
do
  {
    IFS= read -r line1 &&
      IFS= read -r line2 &&
      case $line2 in
        *some_string*)
          printf "%s\n" "$i" ;;
      esac
  } < "$i"
done
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you for commenting. Edit according to recommendations.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks again. Hope I satisfy POSIX compatibility at last. If not so - please be free to edit.